# Supported snooze units / formats for Outlook reminders... and how to guard against typos

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

The Reminders window in Outlook 2010 gives you a dropdown list of Snooze options, but you can also type your own.  If I type `foo`, Outlook responds with 'The snooze time "foo" is invalid. Enter a valid snooze time.'  But if I type `10 foos`, Outlook doesn't complain and the reminder is hidden. *It appears as if the reminder never comes back* - it's just dismissed forever with no warning.

Since I'd like to avoid losing my reminders unpredictably... is there any way to enable stricter warnings in case I make a typo like "2 houres"? (In a case like that it would be highly non-obvious that the reminder is lost, because I wouldn't expect it to pop up again for a while anyway).

Related question: Is the list of supported formats documented anywhere? I couldn't find any online documentation for the syntax, but it definitely supports some things that are not in the dropdown list (e.g. the shorthand "min" instead of "minutes").

Comment: Wow.  Did you test?  What happaned in "2 houres" or 90 seconds?

Comment: You tell us.  Did the reminder come back after 10 minutes?  This seems like you can answer it yourself easily enough

Comment: Ok, I've rewritten the question to be more about the part that I haven't been able to answer on my own. (As far as I can tell, the reminders really do just disappear forever, so I've stated that above now). Hope that's enough to remove the downvote...

Answer (score 2):

After a ton of experimentation, the here's what I've found...

Outlook has a short list of **recognized time units**, though it's not documented anywhere. This includes shorthand forms of the words:

- `minute`, `minutes`, `min`, `mins`, `m` = minutes (but "ms" is unrecognized)
- `hour` or *any* other variant (see below)
- `day`, `days`, `d` = days (but "ds" is unrecognized)
- `week`, `weeks`, `wk`, `wks`, `w` (but "ws" is unrecognized)
- I didn't test units longer than that :-)

The plural/singular of the word doesn't have to agree with the number you give.

If you use an **unrecognized unit**, *most* of the time Outlook will silently default to `hours` without saying anything. But in some cases it gets buggy -- and if you use `second` (no "s") *the reminder is dismissed forever*.

Here are some examples of what happens with unrecognized units:

- `2 foos` = 2 hours
- `2 mi` = 2 hours
- `2` (no units at all) = 2 hours
- `1 second` = reminder dismissed!
- `2 second` = reminder dismissed!
- `30 second` (or greater) = error message
- `2 seconds` = 2 hours
- `1 day 2 hours` = 1 hour (wha?)
- `1 day 10 minutes` = ~45 seconds (!)
- `1 hour 10 minutes` = ~45 seconds

Lastly -- you can use **decimals** in values with any unit. For example, `.5 days` = 12 hours. Decimals that equate to < 1 minute tend to be inaccurate and anything < 30 seconds is rejected with an error message.

Comment: I have seen that "ms" typically refers to milliseconds, so having it mean minutes would be inconsistent and confusing. I suspect that milliseconds is not supported for reminders, so ...unsupported. Excellent research btw.